# Playing Mulitple Audioes with Pygames

Tags: python-3.x, audio, pygame, mixer

```
song=['Avicii - The Nights.mp3','RootkitPromiseMe.mp3','MajorLazer-Light.mp3']
while True:
    for songs in song:
        mixer.init()
        mixer.music.load(songs)
        mixer.music.play()
```

How can i play these songs one by one. It works but it only plays the first audio and not the second. Is there any way that i can make the program run one song after another

Answer (score 0):

I did not familiar with pygame, but try to remove `while True` block;

```
song=['Avicii - The Nights.mp3','RootkitPromiseMe.mp3','MajorLazer-Light.mp3']
    for songs in song:
        mixer.init()
        mixer.music.load(songs)
        mixer.music.play()
```

`while True` makes infinity loop, so maybe it causes an error

Comment: If i remove the while loop it will close the program without playing an audio